# Childview width anchor is not working inside stackView

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview, stackview

[image]I am trying to have maximum 3 views inside Stackview and all child views should be centre aligned 
`

```
     for _ in array{
        if(stackView.subviews.count != 3){
            let image : UIImageView = UIImageView()
            image.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
            image.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:30).isActive=true
            image.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:30).isActive=true
            image.layer.cornerRadius=15
            stackView.addArrangedSubview(image)
        }
```

`
  stackview alignment is centre and distribution is equally centre

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be accomplished if the stackView has a centerX constraint with no leading&trailing constraints to make it stretch according to size of child elements

```
    let sta = UIStackView()

    sta.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    sta.distribution = .fill

    sta.axis = UILayoutConstraintAxis.horizontal

    self.view.addSubview(sta)

    sta.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive=true

    sta.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 100).isActive=true

    sta.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:30).isActive=true

    for _ in 0...10 {

            let image : UIImageView = UIImageView()
            image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            sta.addArrangedSubview(image)
            image.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
            image.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:30).isActive=true
            image.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:50).isActive=true
            image.layer.cornerRadius=15



    }
```

Comment: Thanks man! it worked. my mistake i was having stack view in the storyboard with width constraint